# Disable sap jco traces from java command line

Tags: java, jvm, mulesoft, jco

In our mule server we are bombarded with logs such as below every second, How do I stop it?

> ```
>    *************** SAP_CMLISTEN ***************
>    [Thr 133440] SAP_CMLISTEN: timeout = 2000
>    [Thr 133440] SiSelNSelect: start select (timeout=2000)
>    [Thr 133440] Tue Oct 29 16:27:38 2019
>    [Thr 133440] NiSelISelectInt: 0 handles selected (0 buffered)
>    [Thr 133440] SAP_CMLISTEN: STISendNiping returns: 0 
>    [Thr 133440] SAP_CMLISTEN: timeout after 2000 msecs
>    [Thr 133440] *************** SAP_CMLISTEN ***************
> ```

I tried run some java commands with `-Djco.trace_level=0`, but failed.

```
$ java -Djco.trace_level=0
```

above command doesn't work.

I expect the SAP JCo trace logs to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `jco.trace_level` is for the upper JCo API traces. But your example shows the CPIC trace.
This can be switched on via logon parameter (`jco.client.cpic_trace`) or via global JCo property (`cpic.trace`) or it can be switched on remotely from the communication partner via trace level propagation.

If you haven't switched it on at JCo side, then it was activated remotely from the communication partner (the ABAP system).
Recently, a new JCo property `cpic.trace.accept_remote_activation` has been added for accepting the CPIC remote trace activation with the default being `'0'` (OFF). As far as I know, this remote trace activation could not be suppressed with older JCo patch levels.
If you update your JCo library to the [latest patch level](https://support.sap.com/jco) (currently JCo 3.0.20) these CPIC traces should not be created anymore if the Java application hasn't actively switched it on.

Comment: I was able to switch it off after deploying sample SAP mule application with cpic.trace falg to 0.

Comment: Glad to hear that. However, starting the application wih -Dcpic.trace=0 just means that CPIC tracing is OFF at startup initialization which is the default anyway. It doesn't prevent that during mule server uptime a deployed app will switch it on again via JCo API call or RFC logon parameter `jco.client.cpic_trace`, or - if you haven't installed a recent JCo patch level - that a communication partner will switch it on again remotely via RFC call.

Comment: Thank you @Trixx, I will take note of that.